# Get Item's favorite count from user's favorite itemset using SQL when field is sparse

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, presto

There are 2 tables, **Item** and **User**.

- Item (id)
- User (id, favorite_itemset)

For example:

**Item**

| id |
| --- |
| 11 |
| 22 |
| 33 |

**User**

| id | favorite_itemset |
| --- | --- |
| A | [22, 33] |
| B | [22] |

And I want result like below.

| item id | favorite count |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 0 |
| 22 | 2 |
| 33 | 1 |

As the favorite_itemset field is sparse, and User table is big. Is there way than using UNNEST? (presto)

Any help would be grateful!
Thank you for reading this.

Comment: The expected result table is great. Can't you present the table data the same way?

Comment: Looks much better now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNNEST`  to  to expand the array into a relation and then group by item id and join with items:

```sql
WITH item(id) AS
(
  VALUES
        (11),
        (22),
        (33)
), 
user(id,    favorite_itemset) AS
(
  VALUES
        ('A',   ARRAY[22, 33]),
        ('B',   ARRAY[22])
)
  


SELECT id,
    coalesce(cnt, 0) as favorite_count -- turn nulls into zeroes
FROM item 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT item_id,
         count(*) AS cnt
    FROM USER
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(favorite_itemset) AS t(item_id)
    GROUP BY  item_id )
    ON id = item_id
```

Output:

| id | favorite_count |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 0 |
| 22 | 2 |
| 33 | 1 |

Comment: Thank you for the answer! and maybe is it possible to iterate: for each user, check favorite_itemset only one time? because the favorite_itemset data is sparse and user table is big..

Comment: @sngjuk have you checked performance of this query. Maybe it is already good enough?